# How to align bootstrap navbar to bottom of div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, vertical-alignment

I have a basic bootstrap based layout I'm working on. I placed a logo image in the navbar brand element. The logo is roughly 140px high. I then have a navbar-right menu element that I would like to anchor to the bottom of the navbar itself. I've experimented with vertical-align on the navbar-right but it doesn't have any affect. Can anyone explain how to achieve this? This is the basic layout code:

```
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" width="432" height="143" ></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container" style="padding-top:200px;">


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: what you want to do is place the logo above and the menu button below the logo in the header?

Comment: You can youse `padding-top` or `margin-top` on `navbar-right`.

Comment: @RuiCosta - no I don't want the menu below the logo. The logo is on the left side in the navbar-brand element and the navbar-right is currently at the top of the overall navbar space. I want it at the bottom so it is aligned with the bottom of the logo but at the right side.

Comment: @makshh - I'd rather not use padding or margins because if the size of the logo changes then all of those numbers have to change as well. This is especially true once we factor in all of the responsive size changes.

Comment: Do you want your logo image inside your navbar or overhanging it like in your code?  In other words ...your navbar is only 80px in height so your image hangs down below the bar.

Comment: @JakeTaylor - actually I've done an override (.navbar-brand {height:auto;}
) which keeps the logo within the overall navbar.

Comment: OK, but as I explained in the answer below...there's no need to use navbar-brand at all.  All you need do is change that class to pull left and you'll achieve the same effect without any additional css.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was the right most menu item was butting up against the right side of the page. Instead of right:0, I changed it to right:10%

```
.nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you're trying is to use position absolute for your ul class.

```
.nav {position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;}
```

This will position your menu items at the the bottom of your navbar.  Also, if you want to have your image contained inside your navbar then your going to have to change your html a little bit.  When you use `navbar-brand` your adding a whole mess of css properties to your navbar that you probably don't want with an image this size.  So if you just change your `navbar-brand` class to `pull-left`, you'll achieve a better layout and be able to contain your image inside your navbar.  Here's a fiddle with the layout I'm describing.  Let me know if you needed something different and I can change it up.  https://jsfiddle.net/xbxat9mq/

Comment: Ok, I was experimenting with this concept as well earlier and I ran into a problem which I believe is in your example as well. Although the menu is now bottom aligned within the navbar it is also going to stay at the right side of the page no matter how wide the browser window is. Ideally it should be right aligned to the right side of the content area. Hopefully I explained that correctly.

Comment: Right aligned to the right side of the content area?  Are you saying that you want the contact link to align with the right side of the content in your first row?

Comment: Yes, the contact link should be aligned to the right side of the content in <div class="row">

Comment: The plan is that once the design is flushed out and approved then we would go back and add media queries to replace the logo with something smaller at smaller screen sizes. So I don't really have a concern with the menu items overlapping the logo. But aesthetically the menu bar should right align with the implied right edge of the content area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115910/discussion-between-cj-catalano-and-jake-taylor).