# how to align text to bottom of link element in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have the bottom of all of my text aligned in my navigation bar. I am using bootstrap navbar and all of the text is aligned except the link with a navbar-brand class. How can I get it so that both the brand and the rest of the text is aligned by the bottom of the text?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38087732/how-to-align-bootstrap-navbar-to-bottom-of-div) question and tried setting the position of all of the links as absolute with a bottom of 0 and I made the position of the navbar class relative, but this did not help.

Here is the html:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brandname</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/create" class="test">Submit</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25038/) is a fiddle that has my example.

EDIT:
If you inspect the Submit link and the Brandname link you can see that they both have a height of 20 and that the text is centered in respect to height. So that must mean that the bottom of the Brandname height (since the Brandname text is larger) is below the text of the Submit.

EDIT:
Thanks to @Pete for making [this](https://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DTcHh/25044/) with a red line showing how the bottom of the text is not aligned between the brandname text and the rest.

EDIT:
One solution is to make the font size of all of the link elements the same, but my requirement is to keep the font-size of the brandname at least 18px and to have the other links be 15px font-size.

Comment: Is it not already aligned to the bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25038/?

Comment: So you would like to remove the horizontal alignment of your navbar title and links?

Comment: @Pete No, they are not aligned. Look at the link element's height. You can see that both Brandname and Submit have the same height and the text is CENTERED, rather than positioned at the bottom. Since Brandname is a bigger font it is lower than Submit. See what I mean?

Comment: That's why I drew a line - there only seems to be a pixel difference - sorry I pasted the wrong fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/peteng/DTcHh/25044/

Comment: Right, I want to eliminate that one pixel difference!

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/xgoLt1su/1/] so is that what you taking about? 
not the mobile menu check the height of the inline menu..

Comment: @MostafaBaezid, that link does not mork :(

Comment: [ jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/xgoLt1su/1/ ] check this now.. not the mobile menu check the height of the inline vertical menu..

Comment: that is definitely aligned, like I want, however you increased the font-size. I do not want to change the font-size of test class links. If anything I want to keep them the same size and make the brandname even bigger font-size (when the Brandname font-size is bigger this misalignment is even more pronounced). Actually the font-size change is what got it to be aligned, not anything else in your css

Comment: if you try to change brandname front size lesscss will not allow to do that ..   so you can set a inline css into main html where brandname . And you  want the alignment as brandman have. and @Pete create a red line. so what else you expect on my css :(

Comment: I want to keep the original font size as in my example and to have all the text be aligned. You suggested making them aligned by increasing the font size of the other links, which is not an answer I am looking for. I guess I don't understand what is unclear, but if you would like to discuss I would be happy to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123554/discussion-between-mostafa-baezid-and-user3494047).